# How to enable color blindness in ubuntu desktop?

Tags: gnome, 20.04, accessibility

I have color blindness protanomaly. How to turn accessablity on in ubuntu? I may not able to see so many color. Just simply suggest me a tool or app or something to enable color corrrection mode to protanomaly for entiar ubuntu desktop. No matter its kde or gnome.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what it is you need to achieve

Comment: Hope you understand. @Graham

Comment: What would help? adjusting the brighness of the screen? Have you looked at the options in Settings>Universal Access>Seeing

Comment: "seeing" what is it? I can't find it.

Comment: 19.04 is ubuntu version I am useing

Comment: I've added instructions to get to the universal access menu in v19. If that doesn't entirely help but/adjusting the brightness of the screen might then let me know and I will amend my answer. There are some other options/suggestions I have in mind too.

Answer (score 1):

If you use NVIDIA graphics card, there is a simple GUI-way how to make a color correction with NVIDIA X Server Settings tool.

[image]

I can't tell you right now, if there is any tool for AMD or Intel similar to this, but you can also do your color correction in terminal with [xrandr tool](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/color-correction-and-intel-graphics-media-accelerator-4175577908-print/).

Comment: I am using intel iGPU. I never test with nvidia because I don't have it.

Comment: Then you should try `xrandr` command line tool.